# Bulkify trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

The above trigger is working for below 100 dml statements, if it exceeds this limit, it results in an error. What can I do to bulkify this trigger?

```
trigger updateorderpricebookidofferrule1 on Orderitem (after insert) 
{
    list<Orderitem> addinglist = new list<Orderitem>();
        for(orderitem ce:trigger.new)
            {
                list order cc =[select Id,Status, Pricebook2Id,Order_Qty_Multiplier__c, (SELECT Id,Pricebook__c FROM Order_Pricebooks__r)from order where id =:ce.orderid];
                   { 
                        for(order gt:cc)
                          {
                            for(Order_Pricebook__c lf:gt.Order_Pricebooks__r)
                                    {
                                        Offer_Rule__c =[SELECT id,Offer_Level__c,Pricebook2__c,Product_Group__c,Type__c FROM Offer_Rule__c where Offer_Level__c=:gt.Order_Qty_Multiplier__c and Pricebook2__r.id=:gt.pricebook2Id and Product_Group__c=:ce.Product_Group__c and Type__c=:ce.OrderType__c ]; 

                                       Orderitem rs = neworderitem(id=ce.id);
                                       rs.Offer_Rule__c = tt.id;
                                       rs.Order_Pricebook__c = lf.id;
                                       addinglist.add(rs);

                            }
                    }
            }
       update addinglist; 
}
```

I have WritTEN the code:

```
trigger updateorderpricebookidofferrule1 on Orderitem (after insert) 
{
    set<decimal> offerLevels = new Set<decimal>();
    Set<Id> pricebookIds = new Set<Id>();
    Map<String, List<Offer_Rule__c>> offerRuleMap = new Map<String, List<Offer_Rule__c>>();
    List<Order> orders = [SELECT Id, Status, Pricebook2Id, Order_Qty_Multiplier__c, (SELECT Id,Pricebook__c FROM Order_Pricebooks__r) FROM Order WHERE Id IN (SELECT OrderId FROM OrderItem WHERE Id IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet())];
    for(Order ord :orders){
        offerLevels.add(ord.Order_Qty_Multiplier__c);
        pricebookIds.add(ord.Pricebook2Id);


        offerRuleMap.put(String.valueOf(ord.Order_Qty_Multiplier__c) + ord.Pricebook2Id, new List<Offer_Rule__c>());
    }

    for(Offer_Rule__c rule :[SELECT Id, Offer_Level__c, Pricebook2__c FROM Offer_Rule__c where Offer_Level__c IN :offerLevels and Pricebook2__c IN :pricebookIds]){
        offerRuleMap.get(String.valueOf(rule.Offer_Level__c) + rule.Pricebook2__c).add(rule);
        Orderitem  tr = new Orderitem();
        tr.Offer_Rule__c = String.valueOf(rule.Offer_Level__c);
        tr.Order_Pricebook__c = rule.Pricebook2__c;
        update tr;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is api name of order lookup on Order_Pricebooks__c object ?

Comment: Order__c is the lookup on Order_Pricebooks__c object

Comment: @Ratan  Order__c

Comment: @ Ratan , orderprice book contains one lookup relation called order and another lookup relation called pricebook, after order created order pricebook created, offer rule is another custom object, pricebook is lookup relation on offer rule

Comment: Reading your code is difficult and confusing.  It would be helpful if you gave a description of what your code is supposed to be doing.  What the code is supposed to accomplish.

Answer (score 7):

Your provided code is hard to understand, and has at least one unnecessary loop. That said, generally speaking, 'Bulkify' is just another (shorter) way of saying

> perform all of your queries and DML outside of loops

The most common way of pulling queries out of loops is to declare a `List<Id>` or `Set<Id>` variable, loop over some data to gather the Ids in your collection, and then perform your query.

Your first query, retrieving all `Orders` (and all of their child `Order_Pricebooks__r`) which the `OrderItems` in your trigger are related to, is relatively simple to pull out of the loop. In fact, if you use a Semi-Join, you don't need a loop at all (the query can be done in a single line!)

```
List<Order> orders = 
[SELECT Id, Status, Pricebook2Id, Order_Qty_Multiplier__c, 
     (SELECT Id,Pricebook__c FROM Order_Pricebooks__r) 
  FROM Order 
  WHERE Id IN (SELECT OrderId FROM OrderItem WHERE Id IN Trigger.newMap.keySet())
];
```

The Semi-Join is that subquery that appears in the `WHERE` clause.

Your second query will take more work to extract from because you have more than one condition in the `WHERE` clause.

Pulling the query out of the loop means replacing `field = :variable` with `field IN :collection`. You will still get the `Offer_Rule__c` records that you expect, but you will also get additional records.

If your existing query, on two separate iterations, query for `Offer_Level__c = 1 AND Pricebook__c = '000...1AAA'` and `Offer_Level__c = 2 AND Pricebook__c = '000...2BBB'`, simply moving the query outside of the loop could return records where

- `Offer_Level__c = 1 AND Pricebook__c = '000...1AAA'
- `Offer_Level__c = 1 AND Pricebook__c = '000...2BBB'
- `Offer_Level__c = 2 AND Pricebook__c = '000...1AAA'
- `Offer_Level__c = 2 AND Pricebook__c = '000...2BBB'

*small note: `Pricebook2__c` is exactly the same as `Pricebook2__r.Id`

We can't do anything about returning extra results. Pulling this query out of a loop means that you will need to do the filtering, that the `WHERE` clause is currently doing, in Apex code outside of the query.

In this situation, I think the best approach would be to build a Map. If we make the key of the Map a concatenated String of `Offer_Level__c` and `Pricebook2__c`, it should fit into your existing logic with only a few changes.

Using the general `collection -> loop -> query` method, we end up with

```
Set<Integer> offerLevels = new Set<Integer>();
Set<Id> pricebookIds = new Set<Id>();
Map<String, List<Offer_Rule__c>> offerRuleMap = new Map<String, List<Offer_Rule__c>>();

for(Order ord :orders){
    offerLevels.add(ord.Order_Qty_Multiplier__c);
    pricebookIds.add(ord.Pricebook2Id);

    // We don't need to initialize our map here, but we might as well.
    // Makes the logic in the next loop a bit easier.
    offerRuleMap.put(String.valueOf(ord.Order_Qty_Multiplier__c) + ord.Pricebook2Id, new List<Offer_Rule__c>());
}

for(Offer_Rule__c rule :[SELECT Id, Offer_Level__c, Pricebook2__c FROM Offer_Rule__c where Offer_Level__c IN :offerLevels and Pricebook2__c IN :pricebookIds]){
    offerRuleMap.get(String.valueOf(rule.Offer_Level__c) + rule.Pricebook2__c).add(rule);
}
```

So, now we've pulled both of your queries outside of all loops. All that remains is to perform the looping you need to do to generate your `OrderItem` records

```
for(Order ord :orders){
  for(Order_Pricebook__c ordPriceBook :ord.get('Order_Pricebooks__r')){
    for(Order_Rule__c rule :orderRuleMap.get(String.valueOf(ord.Order_Qty_Multiplier__c) + ord.Pricebook2Id)){
      // Your existing logic to create OrderItems goes here.
      // Be sure to change variable names
    }
  }
}
```

**+edit:**

Your updated code uses part of my solution, but not all of it.
The error you're running into is because you're attempting to assign a `Decimal` to a lookup field on the following line

```
tr.Offer_Rule__c = String.valueOf(rule.Offer_Level__c);
```

In your old code, you were setting this value to the Id of the `Offer_Rule__c` record you were currently working with (presumably that `tt` variable). In my example, this line should be

```
 tr.Offer_Rule__c = rule.Id;
```

As for your other request, adding additional conditions to the second query won't work for reasons I've previously explained. To reiterate, when you have a query with more than one `fieldName IN :collection`, such as you have, there will always be overlap in the results (which is why filtering outside of the query is required).

The `Map<String, List<Offer_Rule__c>>` in my example is the filter in this case. If your old query for `Offer_Rule__c` was only returning a single record for each iteration, then the map in my example should only contain a single record for each `Offer_Level__c`, `Pricebook2__c` pair.

To wrap things up, be sure to keep your DML (specifically `update tr`) outside of loops as well. Your idea of declaring a `List<OrderItem>` outside of all loops, adding to that list inside of loops, and finally doing the DML update outside of the loops was correct.

The second loop in my example, where the `Map<String, List<Offer_Rule__c>>` is actually populated is probably not where you want to be building your `OrderItems` (because you need the quantity multiplier and pricebook from the `Order`to filter out the extra `Offer_Rule__c` records).